# echarts margin between legend and donut chart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, echarts

I tried to add margin bottom between echarst donut chart & legends but it doesn't work
the two ways I tried:
by padding

```
      legend: {
        top: "1%",
        left: "left",
        show: source.length > 3 ? false : true,
padding: [1,1,5,1] 
      },
```

the other by grid

```
grid: {
y: 100
}
```

both didn'twork

Answer (score 0):

in series just set top to percentage so it add margin between legend and donut chart
series: [

```
  {
      top:"16%" ,
      ..
  }
```